# boxplot for single value containing data

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have a dataframe where gene names are the column headers and sample names as rownames. they have one value for every cell.
example:

```
           G1         G2       G3
S1  0.19021657  0.129541639 0.741696359
S2  0.431098317 0.791633452 0.502163442
S3  0.433107132 0.085196075 0.071400934
S4  0.800781053 0.221191986 0.918588422
```

I would like to do a boxplot for every column (gene) - all plotted on one graph.

I tried to reshape the dataframe and then use ggplot, but I couldnt achieve the desired result. is there an elegant way to do this with ggplot?

Comment: Your title and description is a bit confusing `I would like to do a boxplot for every column`.  Do you need boxplot by column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

I will use the new pipe operator introduced in R 4.1.0.

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(G1:G3, names_to = "Group") |>
  ggplot(aes(Group, value)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

---

### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
           G1         G2       G3
S1  0.19021657  0.129541639 0.741696359
S2  0.431098317 0.791633452 0.502163442
S3  0.433107132 0.085196075 0.071400934
S4  0.800781053 0.221191986 0.918588422
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can just use `boxplot` from `base R` on a data.frame.  By default, it gives the boxplot for each columns of the dataset

```
boxplot(df1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(G1 = c(0.19021657, 0.431098317, 0.433107132, 0.800781053
), G2 = c(0.129541639, 0.791633452, 0.085196075, 0.221191986), 
    G3 = c(0.741696359, 0.502163442, 0.071400934, 0.918588422
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("S1", "S2", "S3", 
"S4"))
```

Comment: thanks. I was able to do this, however, we will need to convert the plots into html format, hence wanted a ggplot solution!